# Getting child attribute in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to access an attribute from a child class in a main method in java?
For example, in the extended class I have an attribute height and a method:

```
 public String getName()
 {
 return name;
 }
```

However I cannot access the name from the main method. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show more code how are you trying to access it. If you try doing only `String s = getName();` - it is because `main()` is static, and you need an instance of the object to invoke `getName()`. You should also provide the exact error you encounter.

Comment: i don't get your question, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create an *instance* of the inner `Child` class to get its `name` field as the `main` method is `static`:

```
public class Parent {

    class Child {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = new Parent().new Child().getName();
    }
}
```

`getName()` itself cannot be declared as `static` as static methods can only be declared in a static or top level types.

Answer (score 0):

Is name a private member? You can access only public members of any class (irrespective of it being base class or subclass) in Main.

If you are not accessing the member but accessing the method getName itself, then
getName() should work if name isn't defined as private in base class. If it's anything else - Protected, Public or default package declaration, then it should work.